# Parse error when using variable variables

Tags: php, variables, syntax-error

Here is my code inside of a function:

```
list(${$page}Records, ${$page}MetaData) = getRecords(array(
    'tableName'   => $page,
    'where'       => '', // load first record
    'loadUploads' => true,
    'allowSearch' => false,
    'limit'       => '1',
));
```

Problem is, the very first line of it throws this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ')' in /[edited]/includes/functions.php on line 10

I've tried a bunch of different ways of going about this but I don't know much about PHP. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: What was that code supposed to do?

Comment: `${$page}Records` is not how you use a variable variable.  Try `${$page.'Records'}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
${$page}Records
```

This is not how you use variable variables.  PHP has no idea what you mean with `Records` there.

Try this:

```
${$page.'Records'}
```

PHP will run the code inside the `{}` and use that string as a variable name.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick. Thank you. Dunno how I didn't understand that.

Comment: Variable variables are confusing.  Glad I could help :-D